# Raspberry pi 3 not booting up

Tags: pi-3, boot-issues

got my new Rpi 3, but there's a problem I don't understand. It's just not showing any activity.
First of all I don't have any external display so I have to use it headless(just so you know).

**What's happening?**

It's just displaying Plain RED Light, nothing more, no lights on ethernet, no green Light. Earlier I thought I've got a damaged SD Card reader but I came to know that they've changed its Push and Pop mechanism to PUSH and PULL :P.

**What I did?**
I copy paste all files of noobs folder(After tweaking it for using it headless)
and put it in. (Now I know I didn't did it wrong because I already own Rpi 2 and I was able to boot up on that using same SD Card with same files on it!!)

**HELP!!!**

Comment: Just try imaging an OS, like the latest version of Raspbian to an SD card and see if that will work.

Comment: +1 to @DarthVader s comment. This happens to me whenever I buy a new Pi and swap cards

Answer (score 0):

Darth Vader is actually correct. This happened to me yesterday with a Raspbian image I found on my external HDD.

Get a fresh copy of NOOBS from https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/